# Problema ao usar json_decode() e json_encode()

Tags: php

Tenho esses exemplos de string que recebo como urlencoded `POST`:

```
data%5Bst_cartaodetalhes_recb%5D=TID%3A+000000%0ACart%E3o%3A+0000%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A0000%0AAutoriza%E7%E3o%3A+0%0ABandeira%3A+
```

Outro exemplo:

```
data%5Bst_descricao_cb%5D=Conta+Corrente-+Ita%FA
```

Quero criar um objeto com essa string, porem não estou conseguindo trabalhar com a codificação, sempre que tento dar um `json_encode` ou `json_decode` me retorna um `json_last_error() = 4` `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` e a string fica vazia  ou aparece uma string apenas com `[]`

O maior problema é que eu não posso mexer no json que recebo por que é de um terceiro que envia um hook para processarmos...

Anteriormente eu somente salvei um log do que estava vindo no hook desse modo:

```
$raw_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$post = $_POST;

log_hook( "webhook post".PHP_EOL.json_encode($_POST));
log_hook( "webhook raw".PHP_EOL.$raw_data);
```

Consideracoes:

`log_hook( "webhook raw".PHP_EOL.$raw_data);` Sempre imprime o que vem na requisição, e caracteres especiais são impressos como a representação  hexadecimal: `%C1 = Á`

`log_hook( "webhook post".PHP_EOL.json_encode($_POST));` So imprime o json corretamente se a requisição não tiver nenhum carácter especial do tipo `%C1 = Á`

Com isso pude ver que `json_encode` só não me retornava um json valido quando o hook possuía algum desses caracteres "estranhos".

Como devo processar esses hooks? Tentei usar variações de `urldecode`, `rawurldecode`, `utf8_decode`[1], `utf8_encode`[1] e nada funcionou.. o máximo foi converter o carácter para � e mesmo assim não processar o json.

[1] Mesmo sabendo que esses 2 últimos nada tem a ver com o tipo de codificação.

Comment: Tenta aplicar urldecode na string e depois json_encode

Comment: Seguinte man tenta isso:

utf8_encode(urldecode($url));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dessa forma você corrige o charset e transforma em json.

```
$urldec = "data%5Bst_cartaodetalhes_recb%5D=TID%3A+000000%0ACart%E3o%3A+0000%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A0000%0AAutoriza%E7%E3o%3A+0%0ABandeira%3A+";

mb_parse_str(utf8_encode(urldecode($urldec)), $result);
$json = json_encode($result);

echo $json;
```

Comment: Se der certo me avise.

Comment: Não sei se `$result = [];` é necessário, de resto, funcionou direitinho :)

Comment: No caso ele precisa de $result pois irá transformar a string em um array, e nesse caso ele precisa ser passado na função. O $result é o resultado final do array. Estranho pois você esperá que seja , $result = mb_parse_str(utf8_encode(urldecode($urldec))); Mas o php tem algumas funções que usam parâmetro como referência.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-parse-str.php

Comment: Você não entendeu, $result não precisa ser inicializado na linha acima :)